# How to print all javascript array elements with looping?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

i'm currently learning about javascript. I wanted to ask about printing all array elements with looping. What kind of loop/condition i should use? can anyone give me a snippet/example how to do it?
thank you.

```js
 var newObj =  [
    {
        id : "1",
        name: "one"
    },
    {
        id : "2",
        name: "two"
    },
    {
        id : "3",
        name: "three"
    },
    {
        id : "4",
        name: "four"
    },
    {
        id : "5",
        name: "five"
    },
]

console.log(newObj);
window.onload = function ()
{ 
    var x;
    
    x = newObj[0].name;
    //x = newObj[0].id;
    document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = x;
    
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <h3 align="center" id="id"></h3>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: there's no JSON ... you have a javascript **array** called `newObj`

Comment: my bad, i will edit it

Comment: From the code in your question you seem to know that `newObj[0]` will give you the first array element, and `newObj[0].name` will give you that element's name. Combine that with a basic `for` loop using the loop counter instead of the hard-coded `0` and Bob's your uncle - not necessarily the *best* solution, but one that you should study till you understand it. I would be surprised if introductory JS tutorials didn't cover using a loop with an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript supports [a `for...of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of). In your case, the loop could look something like this:

```
for (obj of newObj)
  results += obj.name + " "

document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = results;
```

Answer (score 1):

To loop over each object in the array:

```
newObj.forEach(function (item) {
    // print the object
    console.log(item);

    // print each object property individually
    for (var key in item) {
        console.log(key, ':', item[key]);
    }
});
```

Comment: can you give an example print to html please?

Comment: What do you want to print? Just print the whole thing with `someElement.innerHtml = JSON.stringify(object, null, 4);` You don't need to loop over anything to print a string, you just want to format it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite approach is this one, but only because I've gotten comfortable with it.

```
var newObj = [ { id : "1", name: "one" }, { id : "2", name: "two" }, { id : "3", name: "three" }, { id : "4", name: "four" }, { id : "5", name: "five" }, ]

for(var i=0; i<newObj.length; i++){
  console.log(newObj[i].id + ': ' + newObj[i].name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the example presented at w3schools, [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_fornext_header), should be helpful to you. They have looped to create headings of different sizes.

Here is a modified code for you.

```
window.onload = function () { 
    var x = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < newObj.length; i++) {
        x = x + "<h2>"+ newObj[i].name + "</h2>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

map() is a great function to use to iterate over arrays.

```
newObj.map((o)=> { 
    document.write('id:'+o.id+' '+'name:'+o.name);
});
```

it's great because you can chain it straight off your array like this

```
 var newObj =  [
    {
        id : "1",
        name: "one"
    },
    {
        id : "2",
        name: "two"
    },
    {
        id : "3",
        name: "three"
    },
    {
        id : "4",
        name: "four"
    },
    {
        id : "5",
        name: "five"
    },
].map((o)=> { 
    document.write('id:'+o.id+' '+'name:'+o.name);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In ES2017 (modern JavaScript):

```
newObj.forEach((obj) => {
    console.log(obj); // log each object in the array

    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        console.log(`${key}: ${value}`); // log each value in each object
    });
});
```

---

**Breakdown:**

- [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)
- [Array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring)
- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to write to your HTML document (as some of your comments imply):

```js
 const newObj =  [
    {
        id : "1",
        name: "one"
    },
    {
        id : "2",
        name: "two"
    },
    {
        id : "3",
        name: "three"
    },
    {
        id : "4",
        name: "four"
    },
    {
        id : "5",
        name: "five"
    },
]

const element = document.getElementById("id");

newObj.forEach((obj) => {
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        element.innerHTML+=(`<p>${key}: ${value}</p>`); // write each key-value pair as a line of text
    });
    element.innerHTML+=('<br>'); // add another line break after each object for better readability 
});
```

```html
<div id='id'></div>
```